# How to render component if URL has specific query parameter in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some paths that currently look like this:

```
const baseUrl = `${mainUrl}/web`;

<Route exact path={baseUrl} component={Goods} />
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}/:ID`} component={Good} />
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}/:ID/details`} component={GoodDetails} />
```

Now, this works all fine, but what I instead want to do is that I want to render `Good` component, only if the URL matches this `${this.baseUrl}/:ID` condition that we have, or if there is a query parameter called `br=`. I tried to do something like this:

```
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}/:ID` | `${mainUrl}?br=:brInfo`} component={Good} />
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what is the proper way to this with React Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two different routes to render the same component.

```js
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}/:ID`} component={Good} />
<Route exact path={`${mainUrl}?br=:brInfo`} component={Good} />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match it.